# How to add an administrator with bcrypt password encryption in phpmyadmin or edit existing admin user bcrypt encrypted password?

Tags: mysql, hash, phpmyadmin, bcrypt, password-hash

I have encountered a problem in my sql script. I bought an sql script online and I'm trying to work around the script but I can't add another admin to the database and I can't edit the admin password as well because it's encrypted with bcrypt. Hope you understand me up to this point?

Below is the code in the script that generates the bcrypt upon registration but unfortunately, the php script has no admin registration page.

'acct_password' => password_hash((string)$acct_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)

I tried editing the password from the sql database but the plaintext is not working because when I try to login the login fails. I have done everything I can but I guess I have no idea working around bcrypt. Please can any help me solve this problem? Please if you don't understand me, kindly ask and I will explain further.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a little CLI Script like this

```
<?php
$plain_text_pwd = 'EnterYourNewPaswordHere';
echo password_hash($plain_text_pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

It will output a string like

```
$2y$10$joZ9wTiOxd2WiYlr6XMJouHD5J.D6mwmhhJEBUPoak4ZfjB74Dx6e
```

Then you just copy that into a simple query that will UPDATE the password column for this user account on your db.

Just guessing here

```
UPDATE user 
    SET acct_password = '$2y$10$joZ9wTiOxd2WiYlr6XMJouHD5J.D6mwmhhJEBUPoak4ZfjB74Dx6e'
WHERE id = 1;
```

Now the password you enter will be whatever YOU put in `$plain_text_pwd` in the above code